# TypeError: form is null

Tags: javascript

I'm using v5.4.1 Expression Engine. I have a form that will take a user's email input and compare it to the user's email to see if they match. So far I have the form set up and some Javascript on top of the page in a  tag pair, where the user's input will be compared to the correct email.

I'm faced with this TypeError:form is null with these 3 lines of code
*const form         = document.querySelector('#myForm'); (form:null)
const emailDiv     = form.querySelector('#myemailfield');
const resultDiv    = form.querySelector('[data-result]');*

I did some research and I'm thinking that I might have to move my JavaScript after the  DOM is loaded. Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance.
The rest of the code is here:

```
const form         = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const emailDiv     = form.querySelector('#myemailfield');
const resultDiv    = form.querySelector('[data-result]');

const correctEmail = emailDiv.dataset.email;

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let inputValue = emailDiv.value;
  document.write(resultDiv);
  
  {if (inputValue === correctEmail) {
     form.submit(); // use this to submit form.
    
    // just for Codepen demo:
    resultDiv.innerText = 'Matches!'
    emailDiv.classList.add('match');
    
  } else {
    resultDiv.innerText = 'Does Not Match';
    emailDiv.classList.add('nomatch');
  }
}
```

****HTML****

{exp:channel:entries channel="Talent" entry_id="{segment_3}" limit="1"}

```
Please enter the address you used in the past to create your profile information in the past.
  Email  
   
  {email_addreess}
  Submit
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: It does sound like your form isn't part of the DOM at the point you create the constant form.

Could you paste your entire template code so we can see where your code is positioned?

Comment: @seavers Thank you for your response. I have moved my Javascript below my html and my code works fine.